# send screenshot from html2image to WhatsApp API bot / python

Tags: python

I work `whastApp` bot sending a report from Google sheet
I create Published URL from the report sheet and used html2image to convert the report from `webpage` to Image the problem is `whastapp` need image URL and i don't know how can use output image from `html2image` in `Whatsapp` code.

````
from html2image import Html2Image
hti = Html2Image()
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTk9rLOnPZy7xGiww-fZAZoDB4D6Yd6wurCrhl4UZuHGf082pT3nLK8If-3r50bqnwLvu2oCBOB09mL/pubhtml?gid=900969760&single=true"

image =hti.screenshot(url=url,size=( 1000,365),)

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#in whastapp code
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}url = 'https://graph.facebook.com' + f"/v17.0/{phone_no_id}/messages?access_token={TOKEN}"data=  json.dumps({
```

                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",    
                        "recipient_type": "individual",
                        "to": phone_number,
                        "type": "image",
                        "image": {
                            
                            "link":** image**
                        }
                    
                     })
                    r=requests.post(headers=headers,url=url,data=data)
````